# SQL time diff 2 hour conditon

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @CheckUserID int, @LastLog datetime

SELECT 
    @CheckUserID = COUNT(strUserID) 
FROM 
    USERDATA 
WHERE 
    strUserID = @NewCharID

SELECT 
    @LastLog = LogDate 
FROM
    _LOG 
WHERE
    AccountID = @AccountID 
ORDER BY 
    LogDate DESC

IF @CheckUserID = 0 AND @LastLog < DATEADD(hour, -2, GETDATE()) 
   OR @LastLog IS NULL
BEGIN
    ....
END
```

I want add 2 hours condition

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: MSSQL its stored procedure

Comment: Please clarify better what you need, there is already a condition for two hour (behind) on your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is related to [operator precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx):

```
IF @CheckUserID = 0 AND @LastLog < DATEADD(hour, -2, GETDATE()) 
   OR @LastLog IS NULL
```

should be replaced with

```
IF (@CheckUserID = 0 AND (@LastLog < DATEADD(hour, -2, GETDATE())
   OR @LastLog IS NULL))
```